# git repository snapshots vs diffs

Tags: git

I read many many times that git commits contain snapshot of the all repository rather than diff. However I do not understand how storage format (snapshot vs diff) affects other operations.

For me diff and snapshot as storage option is equal. It means that I receive the same functionality with either. Just for example: with snapshots storage option to get diff one need to compare two snapshots and retrieve that diff, with diff storage option one just need to take this diff. And imho such scheme works with all operations (one more example: checking out some branch with snapshots just need to extract all files from snapshots, with diffs it is necessary to apply all diffs and result will be the same as with snapshot).

So, what is the key difference between snapshots and diffs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that a git commit refers to a snapshot (or a complete tree) is a conceptual data model fact, not an underlying storage choice.

In fact, it is usually not true that a commit is stored as a snapshot. Once packed, the "files" that make up a commit will be delta compressed against similar files in a manner similar to a diff storage choice, although in git they may be delta compressed against something that isn't necessarily the previous version of the same file.

My recommendation is to learn the concepts of git and its data model first and not to worry about the storage mechanisms at first.

Comment: What do you mean by data model? If it's purely theoretical and does not represent the underlying data structure could you not think of SVN as having a snapshot based data model as well? Are you saying that it's just a way of thinking about it for explanatory purposes?